# libuv logging best practice?

Tags: libuv

I've got on my program a std::stringstream that is periodically flushed (with a timer) to a log file. The flushing and timer are on the default run loop.

Other parts of the app just append to that std::stringstream and the timer takes care of the rest. I do limit the size of the stringstream (to 1mb) so I drop messages if the stream is "full".

I'm just wondering, is this best practice for;

- performance? Is being on the main thread OK to handle this IO? Can I do better?
- Critical errors? The problem could be within my usage of libuv, which could mean that libuv based logging would be borked?

How does node.js handle logging?

Comment: The only problem I see here is that if you redirect your logging into a file, it will be blocking. So, what I am saying is that since you already employ libuv to flush your stream then why not implement a fully non-blocking method of logging via the `uv_fs_*` + redirection interface? In my practice, I found out that blocking log files can be critical in adding extra latency especially in the case of libuv where all the work is done in a single thread no matter if everything else is non-blocking.

Comment: I am using uv_fs_* to write to the file in a non-blocking fashion.

Answer (score 1):

I think that question is more complex than one might think at first sight.

One part of a good response have little to do with libuv and much with your concrete needs and tradeoffs. While, for instance, some buffering, i.e. less frequent write syscalls, is good it also introduces a problem that might (or not) hit you hard in the area of logging. Reason: Buffered stuff dies along with the application if it dies. That, however, goes against the very logic of logging.

As for libuv and performance, my personal experience is that

a) one wants to find a good balance between writing info out and buffering. In you case my gut feeling is that you are buffering too much and that you should probably write out more frequently.

b) one wants to think well about performance, both in terms of, whether its's really critical at all, and in terms of details. The latter being of increasing importance under heavy server load. When you serve some 100 connections it's probably irrelevant but if you serve tens or hundreds of thousands of connections, it might be too costly to use convenience functions like fprintf.

Concrete example: In a highly loaded situation you might want to  get the wall time once at startup along with the (then) current value of a monotomic timer (which is very cheap). Any time information may then be relative to that start value (a simple subtraction). Writing it out works like this: preformatted start wall time plus monotonic diff (e.g. "03:52:41 +123456 ms").

Another point with your scenario is that a modern OS will virtually always provide excellent buffering, so it usually doesn't make a lot of sense to buffer too much yourself.

All in all I'd suggest to use a buffer of about 16K or 32K and to more frequently writing it out. If (and only if) your scenario is high performance/heavy load you may want to avoid convenient but expensive functions.

As far as libuv is concerned I wouldn't worry. Depending on your OS and the libuv version file stuff (as opposed to socket stuff) may indeed be pseudo asynchronous (faked through threading) but my experience is that libuv is not the problem; rather, for instance, your large buffer may be a problem as it might well be written in multiple chunks.

Regarding your timer based approach you might want to have a look at the libuv idle mechanism and to also take care of the problem of a full buffer. Simply throwing away logging info seems inacceptable to me; after all, you're not logging for the fun of it but because that info is presumably important (if it weren't you wouldn't have a problem in the first place. The solution then would be simple: less logging).

Finally, I'd like to make a more general remark: The secret here is *balance*, not optimized performance of single details. You want to keep the whole system nicely balanced rather than, for instance to optimize by using large buffers which in the end just pushes the problem to another level rather than solving it.

I like to think of that problem field like of the task of moving e.g. company headquarters: The issue isn't about the fastest truck but about *all* of them being quite fast, in other words, a well balanced approach.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts! What LibUV is handling in my case is 1000s of concurrent connections and similarly that many TPS. The overall processing model has been of concern, but I'll definitely take note of the idle feature you mention.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly there are better options than logging by hand. If you are programming an application it's often faster, in both development and execution time, to use a library.

If you are programming to learn, then I'd advice to take a look at spdlog (the fastest approach) and g3log, that claims to have the best worst case.

In my experience, std::stringstream is not enough fast to be part of a logging system.